# C++ Сравнить два N-арных дерева

Tags: c++

У меня есть 2 дерева представленные такой структурой подскажите идею как их можно сравнить между собой,(данные хранятся только в листах)

```
struct mnozhestvo
{
 string value;
 mnozhestvo *parent;// родитель для братьев один 
 mnozhestvo *child;
 mnozhestvo *brothers;

};
```

вообще мне предложили реализовать деревья представленным ниже образом, может при таком подходе их будет проще сравнить друг с другом? У кого какие предложения будут

```
struct mnozhestvo
{
  string data;
  vector <mnozhestvo>  branch;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот функция сравнения двух деревьев

```
struct element 
  {
  string value; // либо элемент либо множество является элементом 
  struct mnozhestvo *elset;
  };

 struct mnozhestvo
{
element *el; 
mnozhestvo *next;
};

bool sr_elmento(mnozhestvo **A, mnozhestvo **B)
{
mnozhestvo *a = *A;
mnozhestvo *b = *B;
int par_A = 0, kol_A = 0, par_B = 0, kol_B = 0;

while (a != NULL)
{
    while (b != NULL)
    {
        if (a->el->elset != NULL && b->el->elset != NULL)
        {

            if (sr_elmento(&(a->el->elset), &(b->el->elset)) == true)
            {
                par_A++;
                break;
            }


        }

        if (a->el->value == b->el->value && (a->el->elset==NULL && b->el->elset==NULL))//сравниваем только значения и смотрим чтобы не было потомков 
        {
            par_A++;
            break;
        }

        b = b->next;

    }

    kol_A++;
    b = *B; // возврат на пeрвый элемент
    a = a->next;
}

bool flag_1 = false;
if (par_A == kol_A)
{
    flag_1 = true;
}

a = *A; // возврат на пeрвый элемент
par_A = 0, kol_A = 0, par_B = 0, kol_B = 0;
while (b != NULL)
{
    while (a != NULL)
    {
        if (a->el->elset != NULL && b->el->elset != NULL)
        {

            if (sr_elmento(&(a->el->elset), &(b->el->elset)) == true)
            {
                par_B++;
                break;
            }


        }

        if (a->el->value == b->el->value && (a->el->elset == NULL && b->el->elset == NULL))
        {
            par_B++;
            break;
        }

        a = a->next;

    }

    kol_B++;
    a = *A; // возврат на првый элемент
    b = b->next;
}

bool flag_2 = false;
if (par_B == kol_B)
{
    flag_2 = true;
}

if (flag_1 == true && flag_2 == true)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Конструкции вроде `flag == true` избыточны, достаточно написать просто `flag`. Еще более избыточны конструкции `if (flag) return true; else return false;`. Можно написать просто `return flag;`. Так, конструкция `if (flag_1 == true && flag_2 == true) { return true; } else { return false; }` может быть записана в одну строку: `return flag_1 && flag_2;`. Аналогично фрагмент где флагам присваиваются значения, можно написать просто `bool flag_1 = par_A == kol_A;`

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то во втором варианте все получается куда проще. В первом вам нужно рекурсивно идти по двум деревьям и сравнивать все содержащиеся в них данные "почленно". И это в случае, если порядок "братьев" играет роль. Если не играет - все становится сложнее, так как нужно искать, где какой брат, а еще может быть так, что два брата с одинаковыми данными имеют разных потомков...

Так что давайте ограничимся структурой, в которой потомки упорядочены.

Тогда во втором случае достаточно написать оператор сравнения типа

```
struct mnozhestvo
{
  string data;
  vector <mnozhestvo>  branch;
};

bool operator == (const mnozhestvo& a, const mnozhestvo& b)
{
    return (a.data == b.data) && (a.branch == b.branch);
}
```

и все. Сравнение векторов само применит к их элементам операцию сравнения.

А дальше - сравнивать два дерева простым оператором `==`.

Comment: мне это не совсем подходит, это просто сравнение одного узла и его детей, а у меня множество элементами которого являются множества и так далее, плюс эти множества неупорядоченные, и мне надо понять как сравнить два таких множества которые реализованы на деревьях

Comment: Если множества упорядоченные - то я описал это сравнение (оно выполняется рекурсивно, не только с детьми, но и со всеми потомками). Если неупорядоченные - вы получили, если не ошибаюсь, NP-полную задачу, т.е. вам в общем случае придется перебирать все возможные варианты упорядочений, чтобы убедиться в одинаковости деревьев... Если на одном уровне все значения `data` разные - тогда чуть проще, их можно отсортировать и сравнивать (или сразу использовать не вектор, а `set`). В общем же случае - жуткие факториалы вариантов...